# Plugin Backward compatibility

Tags: .net, architecture, plugins, interface, mef

I have created one plugin based application, by using MEF. So i have created one interface library which will be implemented by plugins.

But i have one question about backward compatibility,

As i have defined interfaces in PluginInterface library, now if made any change to IPlugin then, i can't load older versions Plugin (which implements older interface) .

So how can i achieve backward compatibility in application?

Please give me suggestions,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stay compatable with previous versions you cannot change the interface. If you want to change your interface you need to introduce another new interface (IPlugin2 for example).

Comment: Doesn't this hold true even if recompiling a release of the domain library where your extension interfaces are? IOW, shouldn't I keep my `Domain` as a separate solution to the actual Host application? This way I can make changes to the Host without recompiling my Domain breaking a bunch of extensions?

Comment: @IAbstract Not entirely sure what you’re asking, but recompiling an assembly does not necessarily break its ABI. And there are even techniques you can use to avoid breaking ABI/API while adding new features to your assembly. Introducing new name-versioned interfaces as described in this answer is one way. Another is accepting parameters through an class like `XmlReaderSettings` to which more properties can be added without breaking code compiled against old versions.